# Docker upgrade link container

Tags: docker

I would like to be able to upgrade container without restarting all other containers that are linked to it.

According to this 
https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#container-linking

> If you restart the source container, the linked containers /etc/hosts
>   files will be automatically updated with the source container's new IP
>   address, allowing linked communication to continue.

Sounds great, but I don't want to just restart. I need to upgrade to newer version. And its not working.

Lets see this example from article above:

```
sudo docker run -d --name db training/postgres

sudo docker run -t -i --rm --link db:db training/webapp /bin/bash
cat /etc/hosts
```

Restart db container:

```
sudo docker restart db
```

and inside running container cat /etc/hosts will show **new** ip address for db.

But what I want:

```
sudo docker stop db
sudo docker rm db
sudo docker run -d --name db training/postgres:new_version
```

And now inside running container cat /etc/hosts will show **old** ip address for db. Link is broken.

Is it any way to overcome this issue?

By the way, all my containers run on the same host, so ambassadors are not an option.

Comment: The run command accepts a `--env=`, where you can pass an environment variable, such as an IP address, see the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run, there should be other ways anyway

Comment: I think there is no way to do this. I believe that internally, Docker translates container name to ID and uses the latter for linking. When you update a container, its ID changes.

Comment: You may be interested in something like [Consul](https://consul.io) and [registrator](https://github.com/progrium/registrator). These two components will provide you with a service discovery solution that works across different machines and uses names and tags to register/discover services. And, as a bonus, it will allow you to define and run periodic health checks for both hosts and services.

Comment: I'm using something very similar https://github.com/cpuguy83/docker-grand-ambassador. Thought there was simpler way, without maintaining additional entities. But it works fine.